# Save captured png as arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64, dropbox, arraybuffer

I'm trying to save an image to dropbox, and having trouble getting the convertion correct. I have an img (captured using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Camera) sample) and I want to store it to dropbox that accepts an ArrayBuffer (sample [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/snippets.md))

This is the code I found that should to the two conversions, first to a base64, then into a ArrayBuffer

```
    function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(string_base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(string_base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var ascii = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Saving is started like this

```
     var img = $('#show-picture')[0];
    var data = base64ToArrayBuffer( getBase64Image(img));
    dropbox.client.writeFile(moment().format('YYYYMMDD-HH-mm-ss')+'.png', data, function (error, stat) {
        if (error) {
            return dropbax.handleError(error);
        }
        // The image has been succesfully written.
    });
```

Problem is that I get a corrupted file saved, and is a bit confused on what's wrong.

**EDIT **

Here's the link to the original file 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekyhvu2t6d8ldh3/original.PNG and here to the corrupted. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0oevj1z33brpur/20131219-22-23-14.png

I'm using this version of the dropbox.js: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropbox.js/0.10.2/dropbox.min.js

As you can see the corrupted is slighty bigger 23,3KB vs 32,6 KB
Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: What browser and what version of the Dropbox library? And what's wrong with the image that's saved? (I assume by "corrupted" you mean that it won't open in whatever tool you're using... any more hints? Is the file size reasonable?) I just did a very similar test (`toDataURL`, `atob`, and `Uint8Array`) with Chrome on OS X and https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.0-latest.js, and it seems to work.

Comment: Hi @smarx ! Thanks for looking into this. I've added links to the original and corrupted file

Comment: @smarx I've just tried with the latest dropbox.js  and its working. Thanks for your update. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I used `canvas.toDataURL('png')` and store it in a variable: `data` and then i coded `client.writeFile('image.png',data, callback)`...the file is ceated but it is corrupted i.e no contents to display. What could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer, since it seems that this works in the latest Datastore JS SDK but perhaps not in dropbox.js 0.10.2.

---

What browser and what version of the Dropbox library? And what's wrong with the image that's saved? (I assume by "corrupted" you mean that it won't open in whatever tool you're using... any more hints? Is the file size reasonable?) I just did a very similar test (toDataURL, atob, and Uint8Array) with Chrome on OS X and dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.0-latest.js, and it seems to work.

Comment: I used canvas.toDataURL('png') and store it in a variable: data and then i coded client.writeFile('image.png',data, callback)...the file is ceated but it is corrupted i.e no contents to display. What could be the error?

Comment: A data URL is not the same as the data you want to store in a PNG. Specifically, it's a base64-encoded version of the data with a prefixed URL scheme and MIME type. There's code right in the question above that shows how to convert a data URL to the actual underlying data and save it to Dropbox.